# sorting array with block does not return the right result

Tags: ios, objective-c

so i have an array of strings (monthsArray) that looks like this:

```
months array before :(
"November 2012",
"January 2013",
"September 2013",
"December 2012",
"August 2013"
)
```

and i use this to sort it :

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"];

monthsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tempMonthsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {

    NSTimeInterval firstTime=[[formatter dateFromString:(NSString*)a]timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval secondTime=[[formatter dateFromString:(NSString*)b]timeIntervalSince1970];

    return [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:firstTime]compare:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:secondTime]];
    }]];
```

after i sort it it looks like this :

```
months array after :(
"November 2012",
"December 2012",
"January 2013",
"September 2013",
"August 2013"
)
```

As you see in the before and after 'sort' array..they're not arranged properly. Why not? i personally cant see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: The date format for years is `yyyy` (lowercase).

Comment: `dateFromString:(NSString*)a` should be `dateFromString:a`. The type `id` is the `void *` of Objective-C.

Comment: id is not void. id is a general pointer to any object

Comment: Unrelated to this problem, but you can declare the block as `NSComparisonResult(NSString *a, NSString *b)`.

Comment: good to know for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like incorrect format. Try this.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
```

> @"YYYY" is week-based calendar year.
>
> @"yyyy" is ordinary calendar year.

Refer [here](http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/working-with-date-and-time) for more explanation

Comment: yea..i saw it in Martin R's response.

Comment: Good for you! Hope that helped